# XMLSEQUENCE and empty columns

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

The following query

```
WITH TABLE_TEMP AS (
    SELECT '1a' as "column1", '1b' as "column2" FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2a' as "column1", null as "column2" FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3a' as "column1", '' as "column2" FROM DUAL
)

SELECT VALUE(em) AS "XMLTYPE"
FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(CURSOR(SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEMP))) em
```

Outputs

```
 XMLTYPE
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
  <ROW><column1>1a</column1><column2>1b</column2></ROW>
  <ROW><column1>2a</column1></ROW>
  <ROW><column1>3a</column1></ROW>
```

How can I modify the query to output

```
 XMLTYPE
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
  <ROW><column1>1a</column1><column2>1b</column2></ROW>
  <ROW><column1>2a</column1></ROW>
  <ROW><column1>3a</column1><column2 /></ROW>
```

=> I want to keep empty columns (not those that are null)

EDIT :

As Chrisrs2292 has mentionned it, XMLSEQUENCE is deprecated.
Here is the same problematic code with XMLTABLE rather than XMLSEQUENCE.
But after some research, I think that there is no solution.
Oracle seems to handle NULL and empty columns in the same way.

```
SELECT
    VALUE(table_temp) AS "XMLTYPE"
FROM
    XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING
        DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE('
            SELECT ''1a'' as "column1", ''1b'' as "column2" FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ''2a'' as "column1", null as "column2" FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ''3a'' as "column1", '''' as "column2" FROM DUAL
        ')
    ) table_temp;
```

Comment: I think XMLSequence has been deprecated see: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2156389?tstart=0

Comment: You are right, I have edited the above code to remove XMLSEQUENCE. Thanks you.